# Difference between Path analysis and Interaction term in a linear model

Tags: regression, linear, path-model

I have a simple model, where two variables, $A$ and $B$ both cause $y$. However, $A$ also causes $B$.

The standard way to account for this (in a linear regression setting) is an interaction term, fitting something like
$$y = \beta_1 A + \beta_2 B + \beta_3 A B + \beta_4 $$
to my data. However, the interaction term is always very small. I suspect that this is because there might be some time-lag in $A$. There is, of course, a wide literature on delay differential equations.

However, I stumbled across [path analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_analysis_(statistics)). From what I understand, path analysis would model this system as
$$y = \gamma_1 A + \gamma_2 B + \gamma_3$$
and
$$B = \gamma_4 A + \gamma_5 $$

**What the differences in assumptions between the two approaches are and when it is appropriate to use one or the other?**

Comment: In the case you describe you cannot estimate the model consistently with OLS.

Comment: My understanding of an interaction term is more that "the way B influences  y is influenced by A", not that A influences B. Can you add a reference about using an interaction term in the case A influences B?